# I want to retrieve react table sorted data and pass it to backent is it possible. as I am new to this I wanted to know how could we do that

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, sorting

We are using react table and sorting it with react table userSortBy plugin hook. I want to store all this sorted data or its sequence and pass to it end point. Is there any way to do that. as I have gone through documents I didn't found such thing